# Update AChartEngine chart in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, achartengine

[image: My screen]

When I change spinner value, chart is updated on TAB2 but not in TAB1 even if the TAB1 is active and showed on the screen.

Here is my code...

onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_charts_line, container, false);

    layoutChart = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

    ...all renderer settings...

return rootView;
```

onViewCreated:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    final Spinner spinner_nav = (Spinner) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.spinner_nav);
    spinner_nav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            cSpinner = spinner_nav.getSelectedItem().toString();
            showChart(cSpinner);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    cSpinner= spinner_nav.getSelectedItem().toString();
    showChart(cSpinner);
}
```

showChart:

```
public void showChart(String account){

    if (mChartView == null) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) layoutChart.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(layoutChart.getContext().getApplicationContext(), mDataset, mRenderer, "MMM yyyy");
        layout.addView(mChartView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    } else {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }
}
```

What I want is to update all charts in every tab, or at least to update chart in current tab. Every variable name is different in every tab Fragment.